# Enable to query according to the field parameters via SOLR/CURL

Tags: curl, solr

I'm new to SOLR, so sorry if my question sounds weird or too nooby. This is the example of my objects in JSON.

```
    "id":"book2",
    "cat":["fantasy"],
    "pubyear_i":1996,
    "title":["A Game of Thrones"],
    "author":["George R.R. Martin"],
    "series_s":"A Song of Ice and Fire",
    "sequence_i":1,
    "version":1551332807284883456},
```

If I try to search for particular object according to that request, I will be provided with the response:

```
    curl http://localhost:8983/solr/books/query?q=author:a&fl=title,author,cat
```

This is not the actual response, but I'm given all objects that have got "a" value in the field "author"

```
    "id":"book2",
    "cat":["fantasy"],
    "pubyear_i":1996,
    "title":["A Game of Thrones"],
    "author":["George R.R. Martin"],
    "series_s":"A Song of Ice and Fire",
    "sequence_i":1,
    "version":1551332807284883456},
```

But if I've done the following request:

```
    curl http://localhost:8983/solr/books/query?q=pubyear_i:19&fl=title,author,cat
```

I won't be given any proper response, unless I input exactly data that is used via "pubyear_i" field

So I'm not able to find all object that have value "19" in "pubyear_i" field.

What is the problem ????

Also I'd like to mention that key values to query a written between asterisk symbols, but unfortunately they aren't displayed here.

Comment: Please show use your field type in schema.xml

Answer (score 0):

Use fuzzy string matching technique. use `~`  and specify how many character to handle for matching.

```
q=pubyear_i:19~2
```

that is because your field `pubyear_i` stores values as a single string. if you use n-grams(n=2) while indexing, value 1996 will also be stored as  19,99,96. then you can just use q=pubyear_i:19

Comment: As I mentioned above I've used asterisk symbol during the request ( I do not know why it isn't displayed in the code that I've posted). So the actual request looks like " curl http://localhost:8983/solr/books/query?q=author:*a*&fl=title,author,cat " and for that request response is being send. But if I use this request : "curl http://localhost:8983/solr/books/query?q=pubyear_i:*91*&fl=title,author,cat" I won't be given any response.